# The name 'HiddenField' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a asp.net , c# web application . I cannot able to use the control properties in code behind . after lot of tries

1. Checked `runat="server"` property of the control

> Error 754 'AddPhoto' does not contain a definition for 'hf1' and no
>   extension method 'hf1' accepting a first argument of type 'AddPhoto'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

2. Converted to web application (gives ambiguity)

My Designer code

```
<input type="hidden" id="hf1" runat="server" />
```

My Code Behind Shows

```
Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(this.hf1.Value), Convert.ToInt32(100), Convert.ToInt32(200), Convert.ToInt32(300));
```

Comment: Your error mentions `AddPhoto` but you haven't shown it. The title mentions _"name 'HiddenField' does not exist in the current context"_ but you haven't shown where you use `HiddenField`. You also don't refer to it in the question body.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(100)` - does that even make sense?

Comment: 1) Your designer is the file ending with *.desginer.cs* 2) What you refer to as *designer* is instead the markup. So please, show us your designer file!

Comment: Check if your mypage.aspx is pointing to the correct .cs file in the header of the .aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7csdtts.aspx, INPUT fields of type Hidden are valid for HTML Server Controls as long as you set both the ID and **`runat="server"`** against the element.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s37470tf.aspx gives an example of this using the Submit type and the same should apply to the Hidden type. If you are having a problem with that, I would suggest editing your question to post the ASP.NET client side code that you have on your page (the .ASPX contents) and the .cs code that you have written.

If possible, cut it down to a simple test page in an empty project containing as little as possible to ensure that the basics work for you.  If you still need assistance then linking to a download of those would also help us to be able to answer you.

One final thing to note is that you have the INPUT field within the ASP.NET forms tags otherwise the field would not be considered part of the ASP submission if I remember correctly.